# CSS float right weird behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have 2 threads in an imageboard stacked on top of each other, each thread has some text and an image file.

I want images to be always on right of the thread, instead of being on top of reply button.

When I float image to right by float: right;  **the images keep stacking on top of each other instead and form a branch like structure**

How do I force images with **post-image class** to not break `<div>` structure of following thread and stay on right of screen?

```
<div class="you" id="thread_27" data-board="b" align="Right">
  <div class="files">
    <div class="file">
      <p class="fileinfo">File: <a href="/b/src/1454704253855.jpg">1454704253855.jpg</a> <span class="unimportant">(78.69 KB, 1024x768, <span class="postfilename">soft-color-background.jpg</span>)</span>
      </p>
      <a href="/b/src/1454704253855.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="post-image" src="/b/thumb/1454704253855.png" style="width: 255px; height: 192px; max-width: 98%;" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post op" id="op_27">
    <p class="intro">
      <input class="delete" name="delete_27" id="delete_27" type="checkbox">
      <label for="delete_27"><span class="name">Anonymous (You)</span>
        <time data-local="true" datetime="2016-02-05T20:30:54Z">02/05/16 (Fri) 22:30:54</time>
      </label>&nbsp;<a class="post_no" id="post_no_27" onclick="highlightReply(27)" href="/b/res/27.html#27">No.</a><a class="post_no" onclick="citeReply(27)" href="/b/res/27.html#q27">27</a><a href="/b/res/27.html">[Reply]</a></p>
    <div class="body">xxxxxx2</div>
  </div>
  <br class="clear">
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="you" id="thread_26" data-board="b" align="Right">
  <div class="files">
    <div class="file">
      <p class="fileinfo">File: <a href="/b/src/1454704190918.jpg">1454704190918.jpg</a> <span class="unimportant">(157.33 KB, 1024x768, <span class="postfilename" title="mac-style-presentation-background.jpg">mac-style-presentation-bac….jpg</span>)</span>
      </p>
      <a href="/b/src/1454704190918.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="post-image" src="/b/thumb/1454704190918.png" style="width: 255px; height: 192px; max-width: 98%;" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post op" id="op_26">
    <p class="intro">
      <input class="delete" name="delete_26" id="delete_26" type="checkbox">
      <label for="delete_26"><span class="name">Anonymous (You)</span>
        <time data-local="true" datetime="2016-02-05T20:29:51Z">02/05/16 (Fri) 22:29:51</time>
      </label>&nbsp;<a class="post_no" id="post_no_26" onclick="highlightReply(26)" href="/b/res/26.html#26">No.</a><a class="post_no" onclick="citeReply(26)" href="/b/res/26.html#q26">26</a><a href="/b/res/26.html">[Reply]</a></p>
    <div class="body">xxxxx</div>
  </div>
  <br class="clear">
  <hr>
</div>
```

when I add CSS

```
.post-image
{
  float: right;
}
```

it breaks everything.

[jsfiddle before](http://jsfiddle.net/069s6dtb/)

[js fiddle after floating post-image to the right](http://jsfiddle.net/k8g53mec/2/)

Comment: `.you {clear:right}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use flexbox (no way to old browsers) try something like:

```
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.col1{
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    align-self: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col2{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 1 45px;
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

on a html strukture like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of `float` left or right. `clear` controls the float behavior hence, the ideal way is to make all the float properties inside a container usually div. Sometimes,  browser renders it differently so whenever coming to a new container or sibling, ideal way is to `clear` the `float`(if you don't need the floating property).
In your code you could probably

***Add this:***

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
 }
```

to better understand. Also don't forget to play with it to put it ideally where it is required.

Comment: If that doesn't entirely solve your problem check margin and line-height stuff. It should be fixed with a clear afterwards, but does break in some older browsers from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more div with "clear: both" styling will fix your problem.

```
<div class="file">
   your code here...
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dinker/k8g53mec/3/)